# Weird behaviour with HTML comment inside javascript string

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<script>
function x(){
     test1 = '<script><!--';
     test2 = '<script>';
    }
    alert(1);
</script>
<script>
alert(2);
</script>
```

The expected output is that it pops two alerts: `alert(1)` and `alert(2)`, however, it seems like the `<!--` comment causes the browser to actually comment out the closing `</script>` tag which doesn't make sense! 
When I run `document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].text` in the console I get:

```
function x(){
        test1 = '<script><!--';
        test2 = '<script>';
    }
    alert(1);
</script>
<script>
alert(2);
</script>
```

Is there an explanation for this weird behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have them in separate script tags?

Comment: @Jack just for testing. Just wanted to see what's inside my first <script> tag when calling `document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].text`

Comment: @QuentinUK That's a different issue, it only affects `</script>`

Comment: A little test reveals that the script tags inside the JS literals are not the offenders, it works with replacing the original `test1` assignment with `test1 = '<script><!-'+'-';`.

Comment: @QuentinUK that's about splitting `</script>` but in this case it's `<script>` and `<!--` that are causing the issue.

Comment: I'd expect that to be a parser error. Lexing the JS literals should obviously not insert html tokens into the token stream. The erroneous behavior persists when adding a `type="text/javascript"` attribute to the first outer `script`tag. Tests run on Chrome 80.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically ( more than 20 years ago), programmers could wrap their script code within HTML comment tags, within  script elements, to prevent browsers which *did not support script tags* from displaying script text in the page body. You can still put HTML comment tags, which are ignored, around script inside a scripting context:

```html
<script>
    <!--
    alert(" inside HTML comment tags")
    -->
</script>
```

The HTML parser is also responsible for finding the script end tag, `</script>`, so it can pass text content of the HTML element to the Javascript engine for language parsing. For this reason you can't put an unescaped "</script>" in javascript content (in a string or comment) without ending the script block - the HTML parser is looking at the text first.

The [HTML living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) lists some suggestions on how to avoid problems:

> The easiest and safest way to avoid the rather strange restrictions described in this section is to always escape an ASCII case-insensitive match for "<!--" as "<\!--", "<script" as "<\script", and "</script" as "<\/script" when these sequences appear in literals in scripts (e.g. in strings, regular expressions, or comments), and to avoid writing code that uses such constructs in expressions. Doing so avoids the pitfalls that the restrictions in this section are prone to triggering: namely, that, for historical reasons, parsing of script blocks in HTML is a strange and exotic practice that acts unintuitively in the face of these sequences.

Actually I find opening tags are acceptable within JavaScript because the HTML parser is looking for an end script tag, but I have no grounds to complain if it doesn't work in all browsers.

So the recommended solution is to backslash escape the HTML comment delimiters within JavaScript code. More interestingly it also works if you close the HTML comment within a comment - the code works as written:

```
<script>
function x(){
        test1 = '<script><!--'; // --> close HTML comment
        test2 = '<script>';
    }
    alert(1);
</script>
```

This fits my definition of going down a rabbit hole however, and I would recommend escaping the comment delimiters as suggested in the standard.

---

**TLDR;**

`<script>` tags were introduced into an HTML environment that didn't have them (HTML2?) last century using two hacks:

1. Web authors were advised to start and end script elements with HTML comment delimiters, and perhaps SGML cdata section declarations as well, resulting in inline script tags looking like:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   <!-- <![CDATA[
       //script content here
   // ]]> -->
   </script>
   ```

   This resulted in HTML parsers that didn't know about script elements treating the text content of an unknown `<script>` tag as comment and not rendering it in page content.

   It also meant that, while skipping HTML comment text looking for end of comment characters (`-->`), the HTML parser would happily skip over end script tags that would otherwise have ended the opening SCRIPT tag it knew about.

   Over time and evolution of HTML standards, web authors stopped including CDATA content declarations, HTML comment declarations, and eventually the type attribute resulting in the HTML5 JavaScript tag set in use today:

   ```
   <script>
       // script content here
   </sript>
   ```

   However, in order not to break the web, the underlying hack **never went away**.
2. HTML parsers that did know about SCRIPT tags provided the entire text content of the tag to JavaScript engines - but would still skip over end script tags within unclosed HTML comment. The JavaScript engine was also hacked to effectively treat HTML comment opening and delimiting tags in white space as part of white space. **To my knowledge this was never documented anywhere**. You can only deduce the hack by enclosing script *in an external script file* within HTML comment tags and noticing Mozilla Firefox (adapted from Netscape Corporation's code base) is unaffected.

The script posted starts an HTML comment recognized by the HTML parser in the line setting `temp1`. The HTML parser then tries to find the end of the HTML comment (which is missing) and deems the script tag to be invalid because it has no detectable end tag. If the remainder of the document does not contain `-->` it too is part of HTML comment, and any body content following the script will not be rendered either.